# No intellisense in Azure Function Project in my VS Code solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, omnisharp

I added a Azure Function project to my VS Code solution (has other projects) but I'm not receiving any intellisense support. Is this normal, is there no intellisense support for Azure functions?

Do I need to add something, somewhere to get intellisense for these types of projects?

FYI - Maybe it's the way I added the Azure Function, it was added as a project to a solution. And I have other C# projects in the solution that are working fine. If I create a new Azure Function project on it's own, itellisense works fine, just not in a solution with other projects.

Using:
C#
VS Code latest version
.Net 5
latest Azure Function tools lib
C# extension v1.23.11

**UPDATE -** looks like I'm getting some errors in the OmniSharp log when checking for intelliense on a line of code in the Azure Function.

> Received response for /v2/getcodeactions but could not find request.
> [info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
> Miscellaneous file: /Users/charlespareto/TestClone1/yogabandy2020/Azure/Functions/ServiceBusQueueTrigger.cs added to workspace
> Received response for /v2/codestructure but could not find request.
> Received response for /quickinfo but could not find request.
> Received response for /v2/codestructure but could not find request.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer -

I had to add the .csproj to the .sln file in order for OmniSharp to recognize it.

Comment: I opened `.csproj` with Visual Studio for Mac and after restarting Visual Studio Code I got IntelliSense. It seems an `.sln` is required, and it wasn't given when creating the Azure Function

Comment: Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy. I hadn't added the Functions project to the solution. duh.

Answer (score 0):

On my side it is no problem:

[image]

Maybe you need to install related modules. And make sure you install the python plugin of VS Code.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm not using Python. I'm using C#. I edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and the .csproj was already added to the .sln. Restarting OmniSharp fixed it for me. Steps:

Open Command Palette (cmd+shift+p / ctrl+shift+p) -> type OmniSharp -> select OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

With a multi-root workspace configuration, I was able to solve this by changing to the new Azure Functions project in the OmniSharp configuration. I am not using a .sln file.

Open Command Palette (`CTRL + SHIFT + P` / `CMD + SHIFT + P`) > OmniSharp: Select Project > (Choose the new project)